# Finding the common of tangency

Tags: tangent-line

There're $2$ curves: $y=x^3-2x+1$ and $y=x^2+2ax+1$.

They passes through the same point and have a common tangent at that point.
And I'd like to find the common point of tangency and the value of $a$.

**My attempts:**

Let $f(x)=x^3-2x+1$ and $g(x)=x^2+2ax+1$
I have tried to use $x=k$ as the common point.
Therefore the tangent is $(k, k^2-2k+1)$.

But I don't know the steps afterwards.  Please help me to solve this question

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. You want to solve
$$
x^3-2x+1=x^2+2ax+1 \quad (\text{same point})
$$ and
$$
3x^2-2=2x+2a \quad (\text{common tangent at that point}).
$$